# Jenkins: dockerfile agent commands not run in container

Tags: docker, jenkins

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile true
    }

    stages {
        stage('Run tests') {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
                sh 'vendor/bin/phpunit'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm running Jenkins, and although I am able to build the image successfully, "Run tests" is run *outside* of the new container in the host. This is not good; I want the command to run from within the new container built with the help of the dockerfile agent.

I know that the shell command is run in the host, because I've already tried debugging with `sh pwd` to which I got `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/youtube-delete-tracker_jenkins`.

Here is the end of the output in the console for the Jenkins job:

```
Step 18/18 : RUN chmod a+rw database/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0fedd44ea512
Successfully built 0fedd44ea512
Successfully tagged e74bf5ee4aa59afc2c4524c57a81bdff8a341140:latest
[Pipeline] dockerFingerprintFrom
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . e74bf5ee4aa59afc2c4524c57a81bdff8a341140
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 112:116 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow:rw,z -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow@tmp:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** e74bf5ee4aa59afc2c4524c57a81bdff8a341140 cat
$ docker top 64bbdf257492046835d7cfc17413fb2d78c858234aa5936d7427721f0038742b -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run tests)
[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow
[Pipeline] sh
+ vendor/bin/phpunit
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow@tmp/durable-4049973d/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow@tmp/durable-4049973d/script.sh: vendor/bin/phpunit: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 64bbdf257492046835d7cfc17413fb2d78c858234aa5936d7427721f0038742b
$ docker rm -f 64bbdf257492046835d7cfc17413fb2d78c858234aa5936d7427721f0038742b
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

As you can see, `pwd` gives me a path on the host (the Jenkins job folder), and `vendor/bin/phpunit` was not found (which should be there in the container, because the package manager successfully built it as per the docker build output that I didn't include).

So how can I get the sh commands running from within the container? Or alternatively how do I get the image tag name generated by the dockerfile agent so that I could manually do `docker run` from outside the new container to run the new container?

INFO: The issue doesn't seem to have to do with the Declarative Pipelines, because I just tried doing it Imperative style and also get the same `pwd` of the Jenkins container: https://github.com/amcsi/youtube-delete-tracker/blob/4bf584a358c9fecf02bc239469355a2db5816905/Jenkinsfile.groovy#L6

INFO 2: At first I thought this was an Jenkins-within-Docker issue, and I wrote my question as such... but it turned out I was getting the same issue if I ran Jenkins on my host rather than within a container.

INFO 3: Versions...

```
Jenkins ver. 2.150.1
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

Comment: can you add the docker image build step? is it something like: new_image = docker.build(docker_image_name)

Comment: @ShailynOrtiz if I wish to go with the Pipeline route and not the scripted route. Also because I want to leverage Jenkins' automatic cleaning up of the image when the pipeline is finished.

Comment: @ShailynOrtiz I've just tried doing it in the way you said, and I got the same bad result even in the Imperative way. I've added this to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Jenkins mounts its local workspace into the docker container, and cd into it automatically. Therefore, the WORKDIR you set in Dockerfile gets over-ridden. In your console output, the `docker run` command shows this fact:

`docker run -t -d -u 112:116 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ube-delete-tracker_stackoverflow:rw,z`

From docker run man page (`man docker run`):

> ```
>    -w, --workdir=""
>       Working directory inside the container
> ```
>
> The default working directory for running binaries within a container is the root directory (/). The developer can set a different
>   default with the
>          Dockerfile WORKDIR instruction. The operator can override the working directory by using the -w option.
>
> ```
>    -v|--volume[=[[HOST-DIR:]CONTAINER-DIR[:OPTIONS]]]
>       Create a bind mount.
> ```
>
> If you specify, -v /HOST-DIR:/CONTAINER-DIR, Docker
>   bind mounts /HOST-DIR in the host to /CONTAINER-DIR in the Docker
>   container. If 'HOST-DIR' is omitted,  Docker automatically creates the new
>   volume on the host.  The OPTIONS are a comma delimited list and can be:

So, you need to manually cd into your own $WORKDIR first before executing the said commands. Btw, you might also want to create a symbolic link (`ln -s`) from jenkins volume mount dir to your own $WORKDIR. This allows you to browse the workspace via the Jenkins UI etc.

Finally, to re-iterate for clarity, Jenkins run all its build stages inside a docker container if you specify the docker agent at the top.

---

Old answer:

Jenkins run all its build stages inside a docker container if you specify the docker agent at the top. You can verify under which executor and slave the build is running on using environment variables.

So, first find out an environment variable that is specific to your slave. I use `NODE_NAME` env var for this purpose. You can find out all available environment variables in your Jenkins instance via http://localhost:8080/env-vars.html (replace the host name to match your instance).

```
...
stages {
    stage('Run tests') {
        steps {
            echo "I'm executing in node: ${env.NODE_NAME}"
            sh 'vendor /bin/phpunit'
        }
    }
}
...
```

A note regarding `vendor/bin/phpunit was not found` - this seems to be due to a typo if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes that's the thing. The commands should be running in the Docker container, but aren't. The reason I did the 'pwd' command was to test it. As you can see, it outputs `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/youtube-delete-tracker_jenkins` which is clearly not inside the container. And no, it's not a typo; the `vendor/` folder is basically PHP's `node_modules/` folder.

Comment: @AttilaSzeremi alright. I haven't seen your Dockerfile, so cannot really comment on the folder location. In my deployment, the workspace folder path value is homogeneous across master/slave. Anyway, can you send the output of ${env.NODE_NAME}?

Comment: I just tested with this pipeline - https://gist.github.com/kasunbg/d22132aee2111e63f00e2e1f33ff6db5. I can see that the stage execution happens within the container, not in master. Locally I have MySQL 5.7.xx, but the docker image is for 5.6.37.

Comment: I've just tried using your Jenkinsfile, and for pwd I get `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/youtube-delete-tracker_mysql`, and it's outputting `I'm executing in node: master`. So this is running on the host for me too.

Comment: Well, I actually said that the stage execution happens within the container. At the same time, seems using NODE_NAME env var for docker pipeline agent is not correct. Anyway, can you checkout the edited answer? I think we found the culprit!

Comment: Wow, indeed if I did `cd /var/www && vendor/bin/phpunit`, it works! I had no awareness of the fact that the jenkins job directory got mounted as the exact same folder on the container and got cd'd to it automatically, making me think that the commands were run on the host. Could you please amend your answer to express this?